# Setting WebView Zoom based upon screensize

Tags: android, webview, scale

I am trying to set a webview's default zoomed in percentage based upon what screen type is being used (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xlarge etc). Can I do this in the java code? How can I do it? I know I can set zooming to true which is very useful (wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);), but how can I set a default scale size. Any help would be great! thanks..

Here is some Pseudo-code to show you what I mean:

```
if(screenSize == xlarge){
setWebViewZoomScale(400);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a value in the "dimen.xml" file, like:

```
<integer name="WebViewDefaultZoom">10</integer>
```

Then you can add a dimen file in "values-mdpi", "values-hdpi", "values-xhdpi", ... with the value you want for each resolution...

Then in your code, you will be able to do something like that:

```
setWebViewZoomScale(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.WebViewHeight));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```